# Meaning of "anschneiden" as "fasten (seat belt)"?

Tags: meaning

I've heard a German friend use "anschneiden" to mean "fasten a seat belt".

But according to the dictionary, to [fasten](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-german/fasten) a seat belt is "zumachen" or "sich anschnallen", while [anschneiden](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/anschneiden) means "to cut". So, it could be that it was "anschnallen" and I just heard it wrong.

Does "anschneiden" have such a meaning?

Comment: If your friend is Bavarian that could be an explanation: In some positions an _-l-_ sound becomes vocalized as something that sounds similar to _-ai-_. (That doesn't explain the _-d-_ that you heard, though.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no (direct) connection between the verbs **anschnallen** and **anschneiden** but there could be an explanation for why you mistook the one for the other:

In some German dialects there are positions where an *L*-sound gets vocalized. For example, the Bavarian pronunciation of

> **anschnallen** is something like *[o:schnåin]*

where *å* denotes a dark *a* sound and the Bavarian pronunciation of

> **anschneiden** is something like *[o:schnain]*.

(For this custom-made phonemic transcription see for example [this Bavarian dictionary](http://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/schm-schw.html).)

So in Bavarian the words **anschnallen** and **anschneiden** are pronounced very similarly but the *ai* diphthongs are different. There may be other regions/dialects where both words have a similar pronunciation.

Possibly your friend is a speaker of one of these dialects that have an *L*-vocalization, so that in his/her speech both words are similar.

Comment: To be precise: the transcription of that Bavarian dictionary is neither phonetic nor phonemic but a mixture between typical German graphematic ("sch") transcription and phonemic transcription (å vs a). Please don't read too much into the word _phonemic_ here. :-)

Comment: Ah, didn't read carefully. For this, slashes would be [more appropriate](http://specgram.com/CLIII.1/09.parenchyma.cartoon.e.html).

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Nice cartoon :-). I know that normally in phonemics one would use slashes and in phonetics square brackets. However, I just copied the transcription of the site and added an [o:] for the _an-_ prefix. And as I said: It's not even a 100% phonemic transcription and mixes up normal German spelling habits and some special characters.

Comment: That's also true.

Answer (score 2):

"anschneiden" has nothing to with "anschnallen". You must have heard it wrong.